# Retrieve issue number from string for comic

Tags: regex, vba

I'm not great with RegEx.  I need to retrieve the issue number from the long title of a comic book that includes its name and sometimes the artist's name.  Usually the issue number is the last number in the string, but not always.  Here are 6 examples that capture the range of variations I'm looking at:

```
STAR WARS: DOCTOR APHRA 32 CHRIS SPROUSE RETURN OF THE JEDI 40TH ANNIVERSARY VARIANT
DEADPOOL 7
X-23: DEADLY REGENESIS 3 GERALD PAREL VARIANT
SPIDER-MAN 2099: DARK GENESIS 5
THE GODFORSAKEN 99 OF KRONOS 2 KEN GRAGGINS VARIANT
Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Saturday Morning Adventures (2023-) #1 Variant RI (10) (Dooney)
```

I'm using VBA and this is my current function:

```vb
Function ExtractText(c As Range) As String
    Dim rgx As RegExp
    Dim match As match
    Dim mc As MatchCollection
    Dim sComicNo As String, sPattern As Variant
    Dim lPos As Long, x As Long

    sComicNo = ""
    sPattern = Array(" [0-9] ", " #[0-9] ", " [0-9][0-9] ", " #[0-9][0-9] ", " [0-9][0-9]", " #[0-9][0-9]", " [0-9]", " #[0-9]")
    lPos = 0
    
    Set rgx = New RegExp
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Do While sComicNo = ""
        
        With rgx
            .Pattern = sPattern(x)
            .Global = True
        
            If .Test(c.Value) Then
                Set mc = .Execute(c.Value)
                
                If mc.Count > 0 Then
                    Set match = mc.Item(mc.Count - 1)
                Else
                    ExtractText = ""
                End If
                
                lPos = match.FirstIndex
                sComicNo = WorksheetFunction.Trim(match.Value) & "|" & lPos
            Else
                sComicNo = ""
            End If
            
            x = x + 1
            
            If x > 8 Then
                ExtractText = sComicNo
                Exit Function
            End If
        
        End With
        
    Loop
    
    ExtractText = sComicNo
    
ErrHandler:

    Exit Function
    
End Function
```

This pattern matches all my examples except the Spider-Man 2099, but there are other possible variations I'm overlooking.  It is also retrieving the position of the match for a separate purpose.  I'm trying to be as restrictive as possible by using patterns in a sequence that will retrieve very specific cases and gradually work up from there.

Comment: "Usually the issue is the last number but not always" - how do you tell which is the issue number? You need to find a pattern before you can do this programatically at all, let alone with regex.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the correct issue number that you want extracted for your examples. eg: "DEADPOOL 7" -> issue number is "7" ...etc

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to id them.  They are 32, 7, 3, 5, 2, & 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know VBA, but by trying to comprehend the code I think your regex can be simplified to this:

```
\s      # Match a whitespace,
#?      # an optional '#', then
\d\d?   # 1 or 2 digits, followed by
\b      # a word boundary (prevents numbers with 3+ digits from being matched).
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7zfUMb/1).

Alternatively, you can use a lookbehind to skip the trimming part:

```
(?<=\s)#?\d\d?\b
```

...in which `(?<=\s)` means "*match something preceded by a whitespace*".

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7zfUMb/2).